# UnsatisfiedLinkError if app runs from Japanese folder

Tags: java, localization, java-native-interface, dllimport

I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when trying to reach dll. This happens if `bin` folder is located in folder with Japanese name, system language and locale are set to Japan. I need to fix this.

In English environment and app located in Japanese named folder app does not run at all (fix unnecessary). In English environment and app located in English named folder app  works fine.

Seems like `NativeLibrary.load` can not handle Japanese characters in library path.

Is this a bug in Java: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8195129?

Error in console:

```
Exception in thread "main-FPSAWTAnimator-Timer0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
F:\Test\テスト\myApp\bin\jre\bin\jpeg.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter$1.run(JPEGImageWriter.java:180)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter$1.run(JPEGImageWriter.java:178)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.<clinit>(JPEGImageWriter.java:177)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(JPEGImageWriterSpi.java:96)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(ImageWriterSpi.java:351)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:843)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:827)
        at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytesImpl(DataTransferer.java:2203)
        at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.imageToStandardBytes(DataTransferer.java:2145)
        at sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.imageToPlatformBytes(WDataTransferer.java:352)
        at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(DataTransferer.java:1223)
        at sun.awt.windows.WDataTransferer.translateTransferable(WDataTransferer.java:219)
        at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.setContentsNative(WClipboard.java:83)
        at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(SunClipboard.java:106)
        at myPath.utils.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at myPath.opengl.base.BaseViewer.renderSnapshot(Unknown Source)
        at myPath.opengl.base.BaseViewer.access$1100(Unknown Source)
        at myPath.opengl.base.e.a(Unknown Source)
        at myPath.opengl.base.BaseViewer.render(Unknown Source)
        at myPath.opengl.base.BaseViewer.display(Unknown Source)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas$2.run(GLCanvas.java:153)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
        at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas$3.run(GLCanvas.java:165)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas.runInGLThread(GLCanvas.java:970)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.swt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:682)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:75)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:416)
        at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:172)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Paths:

- `F:\Test\テスト\myApp\bin\jre\bin\jpeg.dll`
- `F:\Test\テスト\myApp\bin\appStarter.exe`

[image: console screenshot]

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: I actually do not understand, why someone votes in negative way without any explanation, what is wrong with this question. There are similar issues online, but I did not find a problem with non-Unicode dll loading. This is interesting topic for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the answer is [here](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31652.1570/html/java/CHDBDBDI.htm). `sybase.allow.native.lib` should be allowed:

```
System.setProperty("sybase.allow.native.lib", "true");
```

I need to run proper tests, but for now it seems to work.